# Error Downloading .apk from Asp.net website using android phone browser

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, .net, apk

In my `.aspx` page, I have download button which `onclick` download the `.apk` file.

When I run on my pc it works fine `.apk` file gets downloaded **on my pc**. 
But when I use my android phone go to that site and click download button it will start downloading but file click gives error **There is a problem parsing the package.**

Also actual file size is **604kb** (while downloading from andorid phone gives **22kb**)

*The downloaded file(22kb) contain html content.*

```
 private void DownloadFile()
    {
        string getPath = "demo_Android/demoAndroid.apk";
        System.IO.Stream iStream = null;

        // Buffer to read 10K bytes in chunk:
        byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];

        // Length of the file:
        int length;

        // Total bytes to read:
        long dataToRead;

        // Identify the file to download including its path.
        string filepath = Server.MapPath(getPath);

        // Identify the file name.
        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filepath);
        try
        {
            // Open the file.
            iStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                        System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read);


            // Total bytes to read:
            dataToRead = iStream.Length;
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);

            // Read the bytes.
            while (dataToRead > 0)
            {
                // Verify that the client is connected.
                if (Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    // Read the data in buffer.
                    length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);

                    // Write the data to the current output stream.
                    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

                    // Flush the data to the HTML output.
                    Response.Flush();

                    buffer = new Byte[1024];
                    dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
                }
                else
                {
                    //prevent infinite loop if user disconnects
                    dataToRead = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Trap the error, if any.
            Response.Write("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (iStream != null)
            {
                //Close the file.
                iStream.Close();
            }
            Response.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you download your file when you go directly to the download link so http://yourwebsite/demo_Android/demoAndroid.apk

Comment: This is not bugs but : I think that flush in it every 1k is too fast! Also there is no reason to re-create the buffer on every loop. Is there any case the android have protection and not allow to download .apk files ?

Comment: This line may also create your error `Response.Write("Error : " + ex.Message);` - you need to log your errors. If you send in the middle of data, this error text then your pack is broken.

Comment: @TimVK yes i can download file from my pc, also from my mobile browser but its not fully downloaded only 22kb is downloaded

Comment: @satindersingh I mean download it by just entering the complete URL in the browser of your android device and not through your page?

Comment: @TimVK now it gives error 404.3

Comment: Then I think it maybe is the problem of some case sensitivity. Make sure your link contains the cases like your apk file and if that works try it through your page by entering there the same casing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heres how i fixed my problem

My Application is hosted under Window server 2008r2 having IIS 7

Step 1: In .aspx page add hyperlink set navigateurl as file path

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkdwnload" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Application_Android/MyAndroidAppAame.apk">Download MyApp</asp:HyperLink>
```

Step 2: Web.config add mimeMap element under staticContent

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".apk" mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive"/>
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be the same problem I've also faced with Android's native browser. Thing is that the download action is being passed to the platform's download application (separate from the browser) which reloads the page and instead of the real APK, it downloads the aspx page.

Try downloading with Opera Mobile. If the problem goes away, it's most probably the same problem. Replacing the button with a standard hyperlink would be the simplest solution to this. Though it might not be an option if you need to have other logic there aswell instead of just downloading.

Comment: have tried from opera mini browser, still same probelm only 22kb downladed.

Comment: Check the contents of the file, is it binary or plain text?

Comment: downld file(22kb) contain only html content

Comment: It does sound like the same issue I suspected. The scenario is described here in more detail: http://androidforums.com/application-development/256987-android-phone-download-issue-asp-net-website.html#post3687287 Have you considered changing the button to a standard hyperlink?